# Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (jasperreports)

Tags: jasperreports, java

Формирую отчёт на `Jasperreports` из клиент-серверного приложения `java` (среда `Eclipse`, компиляция проекта идёт через `Ant`).
Если подключать библиотеки джаспера через "`build path - libraries`" - при обращении к методам джаспера появляется ошибка

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException.

Если добавить библиотеки в список `JRE System Libraries`, то всё работает, но этот способ не подходит. Каким образом можно грамотно подключить библиотеки джаспера через `build path`?

Comment: Добавляется как Вы и говорили - Build Path - Libraries

Действительная необходимость использовать Ant встречается довольно редко. Гораздо проще экспортировать проект в JAR. Подумайте, действительно ли нужен ант?

Запуском/дебагом из эклипса не вызывается исключение?

Comment: А в build.xml прописать зависимость на либы не пробовали?